# How to select first and last li in nested ul?

Tags: jquery

I have tried this:

```
$(".menu li ul li:first").addClass("first-submenu-item");

$(".menu li ul li:last").addClass("last-submenu-item");
```

But somehow it is not working at all.

Any idea how could it solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Show your html code also plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".menu li ul li:first-child").addClass("first-submenu-item");
$(".menu li ul li:last-child").addClass("last-submenu-item");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:first-child` and `:last-child`:

```
$(".menu li > ul > li:first-child").addClass("first-submenu-item");

$(".menu li > ul > li:last-child").addClass("last-submenu-item");
```

Another child targeting can be using the `eq(index)`:

```
$(".menu li > ul > li").eq(0).addClass("first-submenu-item");

$(".menu li > ul > li").eq(-1).addClass("last-submenu-item");
```

Comment: If you're `strict nesting` with `>`, you don't need `:first-child`, only `:first` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".menu > li > ul > li:first").addClass("first-submenu-item");

$(".menu > li > ul > li:last").addClass("last-submenu-item");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(".menu li ul li:first-child").addClass("first-submenu-item");

$(".menu li ul li:last-child").addClass("last-submenu-item");
```